# Why do forms timeout in ColdFusion?

Tags: forms, coldfusion, session-timeout, coldfusion-8

We're on CF 8 and we have a CF application with a 1 hour session timeout specified.

```
<cfapplication sessionmanagement="yes" sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 60, 0)#" name="myAppName" clientmanagement="yes">
```

Within the CF administrator, we have a default session timeout of 1 hour, and a max session timeout of 1 day.

We're having some odd (intermittent) form timeout issues on submission of a regular form (not a flash form)...

Let's say the user hits the form page at 10:30am. (I know this because I'm appending the time to the "Action" property of the form tag). At 11:10am, the user submits the form, but none of the form struct is available to the action page, so the user gets an error.

I know that it's coming from the correct page since the CGI.referrer is defined properly.

In my custom error handler, I iterate over any form, session, or client structs -- and there is NO form struct defined at this point. All of the other Session and Client variables ARE still available.

Excerpts from Form Page:

```
<cfform name="chairsComment" id="chairsComment" action="library/save_chairsComment.cfm?Start=0224_153027" method="post" > 
  <input name="chairsCommentNumber" id="chairsCommentNumber"  type="hidden" value="13" />
  <textarea name="comment_13" rows="50" wrap="virtual" cols="100" id="comment_13" ></textarea>
  <input name="save_answer" id="save_answer"  type="submit" value="Save Response" />
</cfform>
```

And for the Action page, it throws an error on line 1:

```
<cfset whichCommentNumber = form.chairsCommentNumber>
```

It works during testing, but when *some* of our users use it, it throws the error that "Element CHAIRSCOMMENTNUMBER is undefined in FORM." We've just started looking at the specific browser that this individual is using (Safari 4.0.3) and asked him to upgrade to 5.x, but with SUCH a vanilla form, it seems an unlikely culprit.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you give us some code form your FORM, as well as how you're checking to see if the FORM scope is available? I can't think of any reason that the FORM scope wouldn't be available to a page if there are no redirects that would cause the scope to get lost.

Comment: @Sean, he said it's not a flash form. @Chris, this should work on any browser that is very weird that it's doing it on Safari 4

Comment: @nick when i commented 3 hours ago, the question did not have that comment

Comment: If you change the code from cfform to just a regular HTML form does the same thing happen?  You don't seem to be using cfform validation or anything like that, so a <form> tag should suffice.  At least take cfform out of the equation.

Comment: edit - I said what Sean Coyne just said but in a different way. So +1 to the comment above.

Comment: Is the application secured using basic auth (ie, you get a browser-based username/password dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

In the midst of a discussion on Ray Camden's blog about [file uploading](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/10/12/File-Upload-Guide), someone mentions a problem with Safari 4.0.5 [throwing an error](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/10/12/File-Upload-Guide#c3ED87657-C21E-2305-C3CEA96FE78D7064) because the form field did not contain a file ... it's not the same problem, necessarily, but it could be related. Unfortunately, the commenter never returned with more information.

There's a post on another blog [here](http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2008/03/cf8_tabbed-form_layout_gotcha_in_firefox_safari.html) where a commenter mentions an issue with Safari and a `cfform` inside a `cfdiv` tag. If your `cfform` is similarly nested, you might need to reverse the order (nest the `cfdiv` inside the form) to make this work.